# Any Shorter way for jquer .eq selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

```
startSliding($("div").eq(0));
startSliding($("div").eq(1));
startSliding($("div").eq(2));
```

I would like to know if there is a different way to add only one code instead of repeating eq selector every time.

```
startSliding($("div").eq(unlimited));
```

The full js file is:

```
startSliding($("div").eq(0));
startSliding($("div").eq(1));
startSliding($("div").eq(2));
startSliding($("div").eq(3));

    function startSliding (div) {

      var i = 0;
      var tid = null;
      var sec = 1/3; // <- you want 1 here
      var images = $("img", div).map(function () {
        return $(this).attr("src");
      }).get();

      $("img:gt(0)", div).remove();
      $("img", div).hover(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        tid = setInterval(function () {
          i = (i + 1) % images.length;
          $this.attr("src", images[i]);
        }, 1000 * sec);
      }, function () {
        clearInterval(tid);
        $(this).attr("src", images[0]);
      });
    }
```

I got this way in another question from some one who helped me to much but now working on Im getting more ideas on my project, and the DIVs that I have in page are changing, sometimes in a page I have 10 divs sometimes 50.Adding eq selector for each div will effect in pagespeed too. so if there is a shorter code which does the same job would be great to know.I'm a newbea with javascript :(
https://jsfiddle.net/jhudrp8v/11/

Thank You!

Comment: It sounds like you want a loop or `.each()`.

Comment: @Albano you can use $.each() for that purpose it will take care of any no. of div elements added dynamically.

Comment: I've tried that but it didnt work for me.

Comment: can u show the code you tried for doing that using looping mechanism

Comment: Can any one guide me in this https://jsfiddle.net/jhudrp8v/11/ if its not a problem for you?

Comment: I will use this on wordpress so the divs number will change all the time and there are more than 50 divs in a page and if I add eq selector for each div I need to put 51 .eq selectors for that but I want a shorter code for that.

Comment: You can refer to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49653907/any-shorter-way-for-jquer-eq-selector/49654608#49654608

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple to do so.
You have to just use **.each()** jquery method.

Check below code snippet for the same -

```js
// Added code
let elem = $('div.someclass');

elem.each(function(i) {
   startSliding(elem.eq(i));
});

// Your code
function startSliding (div) {
  var i = 0;
  var tid = null;
  var sec = 1/3; // <- you want 1 here
  var images = $("img", div).map(function () {
    return $(this).attr("src");
  }).get();

  $("img:gt(0)", div).remove();
  $("img", div).hover(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    tid = setInterval(function () {
      i = (i + 1) % images.length;
      $this.attr("src", images[i]);
    }, 1000 * sec);
  }, function () {
    clearInterval(tid);
    $(this).attr("src", images[0]);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDcMh.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfQCT.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbEgw.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCCEw.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO6QE.gif">
</div>
<div class="someclass">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDcMh.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfQCT.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbEgw.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCCEw.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO6QE.gif">
</div>
<div class="someclass">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDcMh.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfQCT.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbEgw.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCCEw.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO6QE.gif">
</div>
<div class="someclass">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDcMh.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfQCT.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbEgw.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCCEw.gif">
  <img height="150" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO6QE.gif">
</div>
```

For more info on **.each()** refer https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Hope this will help you :)